# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module next.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js

I keep getting this error below when I try to run the register.tsx page in my next.js project. I have a Next.Js project using typescript.

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

Here is the code in my register.tsx file. I was thinking it has something to do with axios, but I commented that part of the code and it is still giving me the same error.

```
   import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Register() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleRegister = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void; }) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/api/register', { email, password });
      console.log(response.data); // Registration successful, handle the response as needed
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data); // Registration failed, handle the error as needed
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleRegister}>
        <input
          type="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Firstly, you do not need to import `React` into your code since it is globaly injected as UMD global. And from looking at your code this could be related to a syntax error somewhere in the file.

Comment: I tried it without the React Import and i still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In package.json, I added "type": "module", which fixed the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this solution is not working for me